# Android complex animation skips frames on view size changes

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to create a somewhat complex animation where multiple views in a same layout involved. The views will change size, opacity and there is an image switcher that all need to play at the same time. I've managed to perform the necessary animations by using a `ValueAnimator` but the animation skips too many frames (maybe 25 frames) that needs to be optimized in a way, if possible.

To show some details about the animation, here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.android.views.DragLayer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Target width is 60dp for animation view. -->

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/bubble_loop_animation"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="false" />

        <!-- Target width is 50dp for progress view. -->

        <com.example.android.views.ProgressView
            android:id="@+id/progressView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:useDefaultProgressColors="false"
            app:strokeWidth="10dp"
            app:strokeGradientStart="#FFC928"
            app:strokeGradientEnd="#E53935" />

        <!-- Width transition: from 28dp to 45dp
             Height transition: from 28dp to 45dp
             Alpha transition: from 0.35 to 1 -->

        <View
            android:id="@+id/gamepadBackgroundView"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gamepad_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0.35" />

        <!-- Width transition: from 19dp to 29dp
             Height transition: from 14dp to 20dp -->

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/fireImageView"
            android:layout_width="19dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fire" />

        <!-- Width transition: from 14dp to 24dp
             Height transition: from 9dp to 16dp
             Remove marginTop on scale up and add on scale down -->

        <ImageSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/gamepadImageSwitcher"
            android:layout_width="14.1dp"
            android:layout_height="9.3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</com.burakgon.gamebooster3.views.DragLayer>
```

The target animation information is shown on the layout text. To clarify even more:

1. The animationView needs to change size from 0dp to 60dp (0x0 to 60x60),
2. The progressView needs to change size from 0dp to 50dp (0x0 to 50x50),
3. The gamepadBackgroundView needs to change size from 28dp to 45dp (28x28 to 45x45) and its alpha needs to change from 0.35f to 1f.
4. The gamepadImageSwitcher needs to change size from 14x9 to 24x16 and the image inside needs to change as well with `setImageResource`. The animation of it is a fade-out --> fade-in animation.
5. The `marginTop` of gamepadImageSwitcher needs to be removed while the animation is playing, from 5dp to 0.
6. As a result of these changes, containerView and the `com.example.android.views.DragLayer` view will change sizes as well.

There needs to be a reversed version of these animations, which I successfully implemented as well, however that also skips frames. I'm talking about huge chunks, sometimes I can't even see there is an animation. I'm using `View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` while playing animations but they don't seem to help either. The operations are heavy with all the view size changes but I'm not sure how else I can do these.

Here is how I tried to implement the animations.

```
// Required constants for animations.
static
{
    ANIM_VIEW_SIZE_SMALL = 0;
    ANIM_VIEW_SIZE_BIG = (int) dpToPx(60);
    PROGRESS_VIEW_SIZE_SMALL = 0;
    PROGRESS_VIEW_SIZE_BIG = (int) dpToPx(50);
    GAMEPAD_BACKGROUND_SIZE_SMALL = (int) dpToPx(28);
    GAMEPAD_BACKGROUND_SIZE_BIG = (int) dpToPx(45);
    FIRE_ICON_WIDTH = (int) dpToPx(18);
    FIRE_ICON_HEIGHT = (int) dpToPx(22);
    IMAGE_SWITCHER_WIDTH_SMALL = (int) dpToPx(14);
    IMAGE_SWITCHER_WIDTH_BIG = (int) dpToPx(24);
    IMAGE_SWITCHER_HEIGHT_SMALL = (int) dpToPx(9);
    IMAGE_SWITCHER_HEIGHT_BIG = (int) dpToPx(16);
    IMAGE_SWITCHER_MARGIN_TOP = (int) dpToPx(5);
}

private void startAnimation()
{
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
    animator.setDuration(ANIM_LONG);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            float value = animation.getAnimatedValue() != null ? (float) animation.getAnimatedValue() : 0f;
            arrangeViewsToBiggerTransition(value);

            updateTranslationValues();
        }
    });
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
        {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);
            makeViewsVisible();
            setLayerTypeHardware(progressView, gamepadBackgroundView,
                    gamepadImageSwitcher, fireImageView);
            gamepadImageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_game);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            resetLayerType(progressView, gamepadBackgroundView,
                    gamepadImageSwitcher, fireImageView);
            animationView.playAnimation();
        }
    });
    animator.addListener(getDeleteAnimatorListener());
    animator.start();
}

private void setLayerTypeHardware(View... views)
{
    for (View view : views)
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}

private void resetLayerType(View... views)
{
    for (View view : views)
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
}

/**
 * Arranges the views defined by percent. Changes from 0 to 1, not 0 to 100.
 *
 * @param percent is the value between 0 and 1.
 */
private void arrangeViewsToBiggerTransition(float percent)
{
    float gamepadBackgroundAlpha = getValueByPercent(GAMEPAD_BACKGROUND_ALPHA, 1f, percent);
    int animViewSize = (int) getValueByPercent(ANIM_VIEW_SIZE_SMALL, ANIM_VIEW_SIZE_BIG, percent);
    int progressViewSize = (int) getValueByPercent(PROGRESS_VIEW_SIZE_SMALL, PROGRESS_VIEW_SIZE_BIG, percent);
    int gamepadBackgroundViewSize = (int) getValueByPercent(GAMEPAD_BACKGROUND_SIZE_SMALL, GAMEPAD_BACKGROUND_SIZE_BIG, percent);
    int imageSwitcherWidth = (int) getValueByPercent(IMAGE_SWITCHER_WIDTH_SMALL, IMAGE_SWITCHER_WIDTH_BIG, percent);
    int imageSwitcherHeight = (int) getValueByPercent(IMAGE_SWITCHER_HEIGHT_SMALL, IMAGE_SWITCHER_HEIGHT_BIG, percent);
    int imageSwitcherMarginTop = (int) getValueByPercent(IMAGE_SWITCHER_MARGIN_TOP, 0f, percent);

    editViewSize(animationView, animViewSize, animViewSize);
    editViewSize(progressView, progressViewSize, progressViewSize);
    editViewSize(gamepadBackgroundView, gamepadBackgroundViewSize, gamepadBackgroundViewSize);
    editViewSize(gamepadImageSwitcher, imageSwitcherWidth, imageSwitcherHeight, false);
    editViewMarginTop(gamepadImageSwitcher, imageSwitcherMarginTop);

    gamepadBackgroundView.setAlpha(gamepadBackgroundAlpha);
    fireImageView.setAlpha(1f - percent);
}

/**
 * Edits the view size and requests layout.
 */
private void editViewSize(View view, int width, int height)
{
    editViewSize(view, width, height, true);
}

/**
 * Edits the view size and requests layout.
 */
private void editViewSize(View view, int width, int height, boolean requestLayout)
{
    if (view.getLayoutParams() != null)
    {
        view.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        view.getLayoutParams().height = height;
        if (requestLayout)
            view.requestLayout();
    }
}

/**
 * Edits the view's margin top attribute and requests layout.
 */
private void editViewMarginTop(View view, int marginTop)
{
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams)
    {
        ((MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin = marginTop;
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the calculated percentage value for start and end. Percent
 * should be between 0 and 1.
 *
 * @param start is the start value.
 * @param end is the end value.
 * @param percent is between 0 and 1.
 *
 * @return (end - start) / percent
 */
private float getValueByPercent(float start, float end, float percent)
{
    return start + ((end - start) * percent);
}
```

Any optimization suggestions? Alternatives? Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Having a fixed width and height on the `DragLayer` (a.k.a root view) solved most of the issues: apparently when the root view wraps content, the re-layout becomes too cost-efficient. Since I knew the max width and max height for my target animations, fixing the root view width and height, then using the centered `containerView` as `wrap_content` seems to have solved the issues.